# Hadoop MapReduce process different input files from HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing a Java MapReduce program. For example, I have two files which are in HDFS. My program will read these 2 files from HDFS, find the same line in both files and output the result. e.g:

```
a.log:
  apple
  computer
  bird
b.log:
  steve
  pear
  apple
```

The final output should be

```
apple
```

How can I do this? I am trying to read a.log first and store it into a hash set, but it doesn't work because the tasktrackers cannot share the memory with each other. Could anybody have some idea? or Hadoop MapReduce doesn't have this kind of OOTB?

Comment: This is a re-post from a question you have on-hold: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505043/hadoop-mapreduce-process-multiple-input-files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505043/hadoop-mapreduce-process-multiple-input-files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to implement a **join operation** on two files. You can do this by writing a **mapper** which emits `(word,filename)` pairs. In the reducer you check if both filenames are among the values before emitting. You can get the filename by getting the **Path out of the InputSplit**.

This is described in the book 'Hadoop in practice' which is recommended reading if you plan to do to get more serious with hadoop.

If this answer is helpful please mark as answered.